# Export Custom Post Type posts with all Custom Fields and Custom Texonomy associated with it

Tags: custom-post-types, export

i have question: I've created a custom post type name "product" and i have many custom fields and Custom Texonomy associated this "product" with it like: images, extra description, type, size and many more..

I have 3 website with all most same content. My requirement is : if i add one product details on one website then i want to export this SINGLE PRODUCT and import on other 2 websites.

Could anyone please suggest any option to export SINGLE CUSTOM POST TYPE post with all custom fields and Custom Texonomy associated with it having check boxes with each posts to select which one i want to export.?? I have searched and couldn't fine related plugin. Any help?

Comment: I have often wondered if a solution similar to this existed... I have been looking for a way to export posts on a post type by post type basis for quite some time. +1 for this, and I truly hope someone answers your question (or mine!)